# How do I install NPM on a Chromebook?

Tags: npm, npm-start, chromebook

I installed NodeJS (via Linux terminal) but it doesn't seem to come bundled with NPM:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
:~$ node -v
:~$ v10.23.1
:~$ npm -v
:~$ -bash: npm: command not found
```

I have an Acer Chromebook R 13 with an ARM processor.

Comment: curl -qL https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh

according to the NPM github, this will directly install.

Comment: Is there a way to install it with apt-get?
VS code failed to install via curl because my Chromebook has an ARM processor.

Comment: it appears it is not an arm problem, but an issue with Chrome OS. [This should help](https://medium.com/@shovelend/guide-on-how-to-install-node-js-and-npm-on-a-chromebook-8d89a35b791a)

Comment: How do I add the `node_modules` folder? I tried navigating to `/lib/node_modules/npm/scripts/` (per the link) but don't have a `/lib/node_modules/` folder.

Answer (score 4):

Installing NodeJs

```
sudo apt-get install curl gnupg -y
curl -sl https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

In my case I didn't have the install script for npm, so got it externally

```
curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Answer (score 3):

[nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) is recommended on the [npmjs.com install page](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm), and nvm has installation instructions of using an install script.

1. Open the [Terminal app on Chromebook](https://chromeos.dev/en/productivity/terminal).
2. `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`
3. `nvm install node`
4. `npm` is now ready.

Answer (score 0):

Due to trying to answer in comments i will attempt to give a complete answer here.

You need to first aquire the correct package for your architecture. As you have noted you are using the Acer Chromebook R13. This uses the MediaTek MT8173C processsor which utilizes ARMv8 instruction set.

following these commands should get you up and running.

```
#first, download the proper package for your architecture
mkdir myNodeJS
cd myNodeJS
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.5/node-v14.15.5-linux-arm64.tar.xz
tar -xf node-v14.15.5-linux-arm64.tar.xz
cd node-v14.15.5-linux-arm64
cd bin
sudo cp node /usr/local/bin
cd ..
cd /lib/node_modules/npm/scripts
./install.sh
```

That should be it, if you have problems, you can resort to the first link that i sent for install instructions